# Python - Splitting an array into two using an optimized for loop

Tags: python, optimization, for-loop, numpy, iterator

This is a followup question to a question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223962/python-operations-on-all-elements-of-an-array-without-a-loop), but it's a very different question, so I thought I would post it separately.

I have a Python script which reads an very large array, and I needed to optimize an operation on each element (see referenced SO question). I now need to split the output array into two separate arrays.

I have the code:

```
output = [True if (len(element_in_array) % 2) else False for element_in_array in master_list]
```

which outputs an array of length `len(master_list)` consisting of True or False, depending on if the length of `element_in_array` is odd or even. My problem is that I need to split `master_list` into two arrays: one array containing the `element_in_array`'s that correspond to the `True` elements in `output` and another containing the `element_in_array`'s corresponding to the `False` elements in `output`.

This can clearly be done with traditional array operators such as `append`, but I need this to be as optimized and as fast as possible. I have many millions of elements in my `master_list`, so is there a way to accomplish this without directly looping through `master_list` and using `append` to create two new arrays.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: So you're appending all the trues, aka even, to the first list. It should be a single for loop, which means O(n), you really can not go faster than a linear time loop here.

Comment: If you have a very large array, can you use a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) array instead of a pure Python list? If so, you can probably do it in simpler code, which takes about 1/10th as long to run, and uses about 1/4th the storage.

Comment: As a side note, `True if foo else False` is simpler (and often faster) as `bool(foo)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress, imap
>>> import operator
>>> lis = range(10)
>>> output = [random.choice([True, False]) for _ in xrange(10)]
>>> output
[True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> truthy = list(compress(lis, output))
>>> truthy
[0, 1]
>>> falsy = list(compress(lis, imap(operator.not_,output)))
>>> falsy
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

Go for [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) if you want even faster solution, plus it also allows us to do array filtering based on boolean arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random(10)*10
>>> a
array([ 2.94518349,  0.09536957,  8.74605883,  4.05063779,  2.11192606,
        2.24215582,  7.02203768,  2.1267423 ,  7.6526713 ,  3.81429322])
>>> output = np.array([True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
>>> a[output]
array([ 2.94518349,  0.09536957])
>>> a[~output]
array([ 8.74605883,  4.05063779,  2.11192606,  2.24215582,  7.02203768,
        2.1267423 ,  7.6526713 ,  3.81429322])
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
>>> lis = range(1000)
>>> output = [random.choice([True, False]) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> a = np.random.random(1000)*100
>>> output_n = np.array(output)
>>> %timeit list(compress(lis, output))
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.9 us per loop
>>> %timeit a[output_n]
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.9 us per loop
>>> %timeit list(compress(lis, imap(operator.not_,output)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 150 us per loop
>>> %timeit a[~output_n]
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.7 us per loop
```

Comment: This still requires two passes over `output`, so benchmarking will be needed to see if this is faster than a single pass that appends elements to the appropriate list.

Comment: This actually requires 3 passes -- one to determine which list each element is in, one to make the first list, and one to make the second list.

Comment: I've just been looking at numpy. Looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), this will be a lot simpler. And, as a bonus, it'll also be a lot faster, and it'll use a lot less memory to store your giant array. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> # create an array of 1000 arrays of length 1-1000
>>> a = np.array([np.random.random(random.randint(1, 1000))
                  for _ in range(1000)])
>>> lengths = np.vectorize(len)(a)
>>> even_flags = lengths % 2 == 0
>>> evens, odds = a[even_flags], a[~even_flags]
>>> len(evens), len(odds)
(502, 498)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `groupby` function in `itertools`. The key function would be the function that determines if the length of an element is even or not. The iterator returned by `groupby` consists of key-value tuples, where key is a value returned by the key function (here, `True` or `False`) and the value is a sequence of items which all share
the same key. Create a dictionary which maps a value returned by the key function to a list, and you can extend the appropriate list with a set of values from the initial iterator.

```
trues = []
falses = []
d = { True: trues, False: falses }
def has_even_length(element_in_array):
    return len(element_in_array) % 2 == 0

for k, v in itertools.groupby(master_list, has_even_length):
   d[k].extend(v)
```

The documentation for `groupby` says you typically want to make sure the list is sorted on the same key returned by the key function. In this case, it's OK to leave it unsorted; you'll just have more than things returned by the iterator returned by `groupby`, as there could be an a number of alternating true/false sets in the sequence.